# DateBounds for DateInterval are wrong

Tags: date-and-time

I am on version 12.3.1 (MS Windows) and I want to get the date bounds of a date interval of a few months (let's say October and November), but the max bound is wrong. I tried

```
DateBounds[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}]]
```

but it gives me [image]. I want exact bounds with granularity of seconds, so I tried

```
DateBounds[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}], "Second"]
```

but it gives me: [image]. This is obviously wrong, because it does not include November. I expect to get: [image].

Mathematica clearly understands that November is included in the DateInterval, because both `IntervalMemberQ` and `TimelinePlot` work fine:

```
TimelinePlot[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}]]
```

[image]

```
IntervalMemberQ[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}], DateObject[{2021, 11, 15, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

[image]

**How can I get the full date range with granularity of seconds?**

This is a workaround I came up with so far, but I do not like it much:

```
MinMax[Map[DateInterval[#, "Second"] &, DateBounds[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}]]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

From the help of "DateObject": "DateObject automatically chooses the first date compatible with the input information:". Therefore e.g.:

```
DateObject[{2020}, Second]
```

[image]

Compatible with this behavior is "DateInterval". E.g.:

```
DateInterval[{{{2020}, {2021}}}, "Second"]
```

[image]

And therefore also "DateBounds":

```
DateBounds[DateInterval[{{2020}, {2021}}, "Second"], "Second"]
```

[image]

This fits with "gives the earliest and latest of the Subscript[date, i]" from the help of "DataBounds"

Comment: As you can see, I never used the notation like `DateInterval[{{2020}, {2021}}, "Second"]`. Your last example is therefore already wrong before you call DateBounds on it. Documentation on DateBounds says DateBounds[interval,gran] gives the endpoints of interval in the specified granularity gran. First of November is clearly not the endpoint of my example interval. It is actually the midpoint.

Comment: The usage is consistent with all other commands!

Comment: It is not consistent at least with TimelinePlot and IntervalMemberQ, which both use the interval bounds.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
DateBounds[DateInterval[{{{2021, 10}, {2021, 11}}}], "Second"]
(*{DateObject[{2021, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Second", "Gregorian", 1.], DateObject[{2021, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0.99999}, "Second", "Gregorian", 1.]}*)
```

Comment: As you can see, I already tried that and the result is wrong in both your example as well as mine.